# Calculating an average speed (simple)

Tags: calculus, statistics

The other day I had to cover a distance of 241 km.

The first 99 km I covered within 33 hours, so my speed was 3 km/h.

The next 120 km I covered within 30 hours, so the speed was 4 km/h.

Then it was 21 km within 3 hours at the speed of 7 km/h.

And the very last kilometer I finished within one hour.

Thus, I covered the whole distance within 67 hours (33+30+3+1=67).

And my average speed was 3.59 km/h (241/67 = 3.59)

However, if I sum up all the four above-mentioned speeds and divide them by four, I will get a different value: (3+4+7+1)/4 = 15/4 = 3.75

Why is it so? Why is this second average speed higher then the first one?
What does it reflect?

Comment: If you take a *weighted* average of the average speeds (weighted by the fraction of time spent at that average speed), you will get the correct answer. If you just take a simple average, you won't generally get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat tricky at first. The correct average is:
$$ Average Speed = \frac{Total Distance}{Total Time}=\frac{241}{67}=3.597$$.

Now, why is this not the same as the other average?

The general rule in mathematics is that, the average value is not always equal the average of the partial averages. This may sound confusing, so let's take an algebraic example of  a journey with 2 legs only (because it is simpler than a 4-leg journey). I use $T_i$ here to indicate time taken in covering $leg_i$.

$$True Average = \frac {Distance_1 + Distance_2}{T_1+T_2}$$.

$$The Other Expression= \frac{\frac {Distance_1}{T1}+\frac {Distance_2}{T2}}{2} = \frac{T_2*Distance_1+T_1*Distance_2}{2T_1*T_2}$$

As you can see the 2 equations are not identical. It may happen by accident that the result may be similar (for example, if $T=1$ for each leg of the journey) but the  equations are fundamentally different.

[image]

Ref: You may also want to check:

[Related Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264250/excel-why-is-the-average-of-divisions-different-from-division-of-sums)

Comment: So, would it be correct to say that the greater the difference between the "other expression" and the "true average" is, the more the speed was fluctuating as I was covering the whole distance?

Comment: I am not sure this is correct. If the 2 expressions were only true when $Time = 1$ we could make assumptions. However, they could also be equal if $Time$ is not $1$. That's why I can't generalize the observation.

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer. Mainly, I don't understand why in your formula for TheOtherExpression the denominator in the fraction (i.e. the lower part of the fraction) is T1 + T2. Shouldn't it be simply number 2 instead? After all, the straight average of two values is found by means of summing them up and dividing that sum by 2. No?

Comment: "The other expression" is not the true average. I listed how it was computer in algebraic form so that you could see why  "The other expression" has a different answer than the correct answer.

Comment: So, "the other expression" in your answer is not really aiming to calculate the straight average speed between two different speeds of the journey, right? In other words, what I did in the end of my question is not what you are doing in your "the other expression" formula, right?

Comment: The "other expression" aims to emirate ": (3+4+7+1)/4 = 15/4 = 3.75 using symbols because numbers alone may be deceiving. The method leading to the value 3.75 is not the true average.

Comment: **“The "other expression" aims to emirate ": (3+4+7+1)/4 = 15/4 = 3.75”** – That’s what my “other expression” does. But in your “other expression” the lower part of the fraction is the sum total of separate times, not the quantity of them (which is 4). In other words, what your "other expression" does is this: (3+4+7+1)/(33+30+3+1) = 15/67 = 0.2238805…  which is absolutely different.

Comment: **”The method leading to the value 3.75 is not the true average”** - I agree with that. I just don’t understand how your “other expression” formula is representative of my “other expression”. It looks like it doesn’t illustrate mine at all.

Comment: I have taken another look at it and you are correct. Still the value 3.75 is not correct. I will fix the answer text. Thanks for pointing this out.